# Push notifications from windows azure mobile service to html/js web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I want to enable push notifications on my windows azure mobile service, i have non-windows store html/js client. I have searched azure documentation and i see only examples for windows store/android/ios platforms. So i am kind of confused if there is a way to make it work on an html/js client or an MVC web app ? if not is SignalR along with Rx a good approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the mobile platforms has a push notification service. The web, or browsers in general don't (with the exception of some support in Safari). The setup you see in Azure Mobile is for those mobile platforms.

SignalR is a great way to push to connected browser clients. Using the newly released .NET back end for your Azure Mobile Service it is very easy to create and work with SignalR hubs to send out notifications.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/30/realtime-with-signalr-and-azure-mobile-net-backend.aspx

However, if you are using the Node.JS back end then the SignalR pieces aren't there. In that case you have the option to use Socket.IO to achieve the same type of connectivity. 
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/26/how-to-use-socket-io-with-azure-mobile-service-node-backend/

On the client you'll have to use some javascript to actually display the notifications. Toastr (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) is a nice option [also available on nuget].

Comment: Just to confirm if i understood you correct, this means that the out of the box azure mobile service push notifications cannot be used in my scenario(i have a .Net backend and html web front end), is that right ? and to add on to that i dont expect this app to support safari

Comment: Correct, push notifications are generally for the mobile devices and use Google Cloud Messaging, Apple Push Notifications and Windows Notification Service. For .NET backend and HTML web front end, then you should use the SignalR support I referenced.